# How can I set the titlebar title for a modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

`self.title = @"My View";`

Doesn't work when my view is presented modally.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319834/proper-way-to-add-a-title-to-a-modal-view-controllers-toolbar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must write following code for presenting modalView Controller..

```
yourModelController =[[Yourmodelcontroller alloc]init];

UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: yourModelController];

[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad`-method you need to write:

```
self.title =@"My View";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My View", @"Comment goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UINavigationItem** property in **ViewDidLoad()** to set the navigation bar's title.

Swift Code:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Bar Title"
```